# Error on AWS EMR while exporting to S3: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to export data from EMR master node to S3 bucket, its failing.
While executing below line of code from my pyspark code:

```
DF1
.coalesce(1)
.write
.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.save("s3://fittech-bucket/emr/outputs/test_data")
```

below error comes:

```
An error occurred while calling o78.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2840)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2857)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2367)
```

Comment: Any S3 dependent jars need to add ?

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing directly to your local HDFS file system and then using `aws s3 cp` to copy your local files to S3. Alternatively, you could enable EMRFS and use sync so that it automatically pushes your local changes to S3. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-cli-reference.html for the EMRFS reference. 
It might be a workaround, but it should solve your primary issue. Plus, you get a number of benefits if you use EMRFS. If you want to execute the EMRFS sync command from within Python, since I'm not sure if there's a way to do that from boto3, you can do that by executing a bash command from Python like this: [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

If you just want to use boto3 to push the file(s) to S3, file upload to S3 via Boto3 is documented here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

You can also use `s3-dist-cp` or `hadoop fs` to copy to/from S3, as mentioned here: [How does EMR handle an s3 bucket for input and output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211002/how-does-emr-handle-an-s3-bucket-for-input-and-output)